# Keeping the scrolling bar in editable and non-editable text box of WPF application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf-controls

In a WPF application how can I have a Text box which can be editable or not editable according different scenarios but still have a scroll bar which enables to scroll through the text in both the scenarios. Right now the text box is configured as:

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
IsEnabled="(either False or true)"
```

Now even though the scroll bar appears i am unable to scroll through the text when the text box is disabled.

Even  `IsReadOnly` does not helps.

I need the scrolling option available in both the scenarios.

Comment: This should work if you use IsReadOnly instead of IsEnabled. Maybe you can give more information on how you're using it to see why it does not work for you.

Comment: With IsReadOnly the style of the TextBox changes to white background although the scroll is enabled.

Comment: Well it's weird that the style changes, it generally shouldn't, but as a last resort You could try setting the Focusable property to False, the user won't be able to highlight the text inside though (or do anything else with it using regular input methods such as mouse or keyboard and, possibly, touchscreen or anything else).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to this is to do as the comments say: instead of using `IsEnabled` use `IsReadOnly`, and use the following setters to get the disabled style:

```
<Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
```

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5909cc3-8ad1-4ddd-8efa-dc14bf0dace5/enable-scrollbar-on-disabled-textbox)